# Herdar uma classe de conexão que está em outro arquivo para outra pasta em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, classes, herança

Tenho um projeto do qual preciso criar uma classe de conexão na pasta raiz do meu servidor, para que futuramente em atualizações de senha e IP, nao seja necessário ter que alterar em todas as classes de todos os sistemas. Então dentro da pasta do meu projeto tenho uma pasta com um arquivo classe que possui minhas functions e querys, e preciso dentro desse arquivo herdar a conexão de outro arquivo que está em outra pasta, para que os meus selects e inserts funcionem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: certo e qual é a dúvida? já li e não entendi, aproveita e adiciona na pergunta o seu código

Comment: Quero herdar a conexão de uma pasta que está lá atrás para um arquivo de functions q está dentro do meu projeto, para que as minhas querys funcionem. 
Da uma olhada no diagrama: https://prnt.sc/214hze9

Comment: O objetivo de deixar a conexão fora do meu projeto é facilitar futuramente caso tenhamos que alterar algum dado da conexão, como exemplo  a senha ou IP, por que não é só este projeto que usa essa base de dados.

Comment: Denis não coloque links externos especialmente nos comentários, pode editar a pergunta e adicionar a imagem, fica muito melhor para todos visualizarem :)

Comment: Pronto, me desculpe.

Comment: Adicionei a imagem.

Comment: O composer consegue fazer isso. Dá uma pesquisada sobre ele e como incluir o autoload dele no projeto.
Agora não consigo te ajudar muito, mas assim que tiver um tempo volto aqui e te explico melhor.

Comment: Denis, você poderia simplesmente utilizar o require_once para buscar o arquivo na pasta desejada, mas essa solução que você encontrou pode te trazer dificuldades na hora de realizar o deploy das aplicações. Eu recomendo pesquisar um pouco sobre variáveis de ambiente e o uso das mesmas dentro do seu código PHP, provavelmente vai te poupar muita dor de cabeça.

Answer (score 1):

Não há muitas informações na sua pergunta, mas para que sua classe esteja disponível no arquivo para poder usar a herança da classe contida nele você pode usar o `require_once` por exemplo e passar o caminho relacional.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../conexao.php';

class ClienteDAO extends ConexaoDAO {
...
}
```

**Mas, em projetos novos em PHP acredito que o melhor caminho é usar namespaces e  o composer para realizar o autoload.**

Além disso, você disse que quer usar esse recurso caso mude alguma coisa na conexão como IP ou senha. Espero que não esteja colocando isso diretamente no código, **isso é extremamente perigoso**. Procure usar variáveis de ambiente para isso, o `php dotenv` pode te ajudar nisso.